# Doesn't get token for push notifications

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I'm trying to have push notifications working, but I have the impression that the method "didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken" is never called, same case for "didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError". Some old threads here on stackoverflow show exactly the same problem, but solutions provided doesn't have worked for me :/

I have searched everywhere and it seems that I'm stuck with this problem, the token is never printed to the console, the only output I got is:

```
Permission granted: true
Notification settings: <UNNotificationSettings: 0x1c009cb10; authorizationStatus: Authorized, notificationCenterSetting: Enabled, soundSetting: Enabled, badgeSetting: Enabled, lockScreenSetting: Enabled, carPlaySetting: NotSupported, alertSetting: Enabled, alertStyle: Banner>
```

What I did:

- Checked that the service is up : https://developer.apple.com/system-status/
- Issued a certificate successfully for my app (APNs Development)
- Running app on different devices
- Imported UserNotifications.framework
- Set Push Notifications and Remote notifications (Background Modes) capabilities ON

Here is my code (appdelegate.swift):

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift


import UserNotifications
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        registerForPushNotifications()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    func registerForPushNotifications() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) {
            (granted, error) in
            print("Permission granted: \(granted)")

            guard granted else { return }
            self.getNotificationSettings()
        }
    }

    func getNotificationSettings() {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
        }
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let tokenParts = deviceToken.map { data -> String in
            return String(format: "%02.2hhx", data)
        }

        let token = tokenParts.joined()
        print("Device Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                     didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register: \(error)")
    }


}
```

Thank's in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never actually try registering for push notifications, hence the relevant functions are never called. You need to call `UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()` in order to receive push notifications, while your current code only requests permission for notifications.

```
func registerForPushNotifications() {
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        print("Permission granted: \(granted)")
        guard granted else { return }
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().getNotificationSettings { (settings) in
            print("Notification settings: \(settings)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank's! Effectively I forgot UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()